# Only rdsadmin account on AWS RDS with full master permissions

Tags: amazon-web-services, database, rds

Good afternoon all,

I'm hoping someone is able to help with the following.

On our main live database it's just been brought to our attention that we need to be able to kill user processes that are sometimes stuck running on our database, in order to do this I need to have the ProcessAdmin role. When I try and login with the highest privilege account on our database (other than rdsadmin, but on further research it seems this account cannot be used and is for AWS services only) it says access denied when trying to give any of the super permission sets.

I'm now worried that there was potentially another God like master account that has somehow been deleted, although not sure how this would've been possible when all the other accounts have lower permission.

Just to give a rough idea, these are the permissions our highest accounts have:
[image: account permissions]

And here is the permission set of the rdsadmin:
[image: rdsadmin permission]

If anyone is able to help with this, will be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: To clarify - when you try this using the RDS master admin password that is set when you create the database, does this work?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is 4 months old but if you are just looking at killing processes then all you have to do is use CALL mysql.rds_kill(xxx) where xxx is the process number.  You can do that with an admin equiv account you setup.